# Find out tables not being used

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I'm planning a repository clean and I would like to know if there is a way to find out in OBIEE (12.2.1.3.0) which tables are not being used at all.

That alone would solve my problem right away. It would be great to have access to a list of tables and fields and which analysis, agents, etc are using them.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get that all with OBIEE's in-built capabilities but it will take time and effort. Best look at rhe lineage solution by this guy: https://datalysis.ch/